# c++: Does the new operator for dynamic allocation check for memory safety?

Tags: c++, dynamic, heap-memory, allocation

My question arises from one of my c++ exercises (from Programming Abstraction in C++, 2012 version, Exercise 12.2). Here it is:

> ```
> void strcpy(char *dst, char *src) {
>     while (*dst++ = *src++);
> }
> ```
>
> The definition of strcpy is dangerous. The danger stems from the fact
>   that strcpy fails to check that there is sufficient space in the
>   character array that receives the copy, thereby increasing the chance
>   of a buffer-overflow error. It is possible, however, to eliminate much
>   of the danger by using dynamic allocation to create memory space for
>   the copied string. Write a function
>
> ```
> char *copyCString(char *str);
> ```
>
> that allocates enough memory for the C-style string str and then
>   copies the characters—along with the terminating null character—into
>   the newly allocated memory.

Here's my question: 
Is this new method really safe? Why it's safe?
I mean, to be a little bit radical, what if there isn't enough space in the heap?
Is the `new` operator able to check for space availability and fall in an elegant way if there isn't enough space? 
Will that cause other kind of "something-overflow"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `new` fails to allocate the requested memory, it's supposed to throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception (but see below for more). After that, the stack will be unwound to the matching exception handler, and it'll be up to your code to figure out what to do from there.

If you really want/need to assure against an exception being thrown, there is a `nothrow` version of `new` you can use that will return a null pointer to signal failure--but this is included almost exclusively for C compatibility, and not frequently used (or useful).

For the type of situation cited in the question, you normally want to use `std::string` instead of messing with allocating space yourself at all.

Also note that on many modern systems, the notion of `new` *either* throwing or returning a null pointer in case of failure, is really fairly foreign. In reality, Windows will normally attempt to expand the paging file to meet your request. Linux has an "OOMKiller" process that will attempt to find "bad" processes and kill them to free up memory if you run out.

As such, even though the C++ standard (and the C standard) prescribe what *should* happen if allocation fails, that's rarely what happens in real life.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I get it. But that question is deliberately designed to let readers mess around with allocating space. So they can get a sense of dynamic allocation. It's under the chapter named Dynamic Memory Management.

Comment: @ZongyaoJin: yeah, and that's fine, and a perfectly reasonable thing to learn. Unfortunately, however, most books just don't seem to teach dynamic memory management in enough detail to be really useful.

Comment: Again, thanks for you supplement! I see. I know it will almost never happen especially for a new programmer like me. It's just the question mentioned about safety, and it didn't mention about why `new` is a better strategy. So, I was curious about that. Anyways, thank you very much!

Comment: An annoying quirk is that it's possible to overload the global `operator new()` to return a null pointer instead of throwing an exception;  so code that relies on the value from `new` never being null, can be broken by something done in another translation unit.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: It's certainly possible somebody could do so--and if the allocation function has a non-throwing exception specification, it's required. Otherwise, it's (apparently) undefined behavior: "Any other allocation function that fails to allocate storage shall indicate failure only by throwing an exception (15.1) of a type that would match a handler (15.3) of type std::bad_alloc (18.6.2.1)." (§[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]/3) (from the wording that really should be a diasnosable error, but I doubt most compilers can diagnose it).

Answer (score 1):

New operator will throw bad_alloc exception if it cannot alocate memory, unless nothrow specified. If you specify constant nothrow you will get NULL pointer back if it cannot alocate memory.

Answer (score 0):

The code for strcpy is unsafe because it will try copying outside of the allocated memory for the **dst** pointer. Example:

```
int main()
{
    const char* s1 = "hello"; // allocated space for 6 characters
    char* s2 = new char[ 2 ]; // allocated space for 2 characters.
    strcpy( s2, s1 );
    cout << s2 << endl;

    char c; cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

This prints the correct value "hello", but remember that the pointer **s2** was allocated to only have space for 2 characters. So we can assume that the other characters were written to the subsequent memory slots, which is unsafe as we could be overwriting data or accessing invalid memory.

Consider this solution:

```
char* e4_strdup( const char*& c )
{
    // holds the number of space required for the c-string
    unsigned int sz{ 0 };

    // since c-style strings are terminated by the '\0' character,
    // increase the required space until we've found a '\0' character.
    for ( const char* p_to_c = c; *p_to_c != '\0'; ++p_to_c )
        ++sz;

    // allocate correct amount of space for copy.
    // we do ++sz during allocation because we must provide enough space for the '\0' character.
    char* c_copy{ new char[ ++sz ] }; // extra space for '\0' character.
    for ( unsigned int i{ 0 }; i < sz; ++i )
        c_copy[ i ] = c[ i ]; // copy every character onto allocated memory

    return c_copy;
}
```

The **new** operator will still return a std::bad_alloc exception if you run out of memory.

Comment: In your first example the sizes are `6` and `2` respectively

Comment: You are correct, I was ignoring the '\0' character and the other was an error I made while editing the post. Thank you. Fixed.